# New Instance of Object Breaks Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a class called `Date` which overrides its `ToString` and returns it via a property:

```
public string DateString
{
    get { return ToString(); }
}
```

My instance of `Date` is held in a container class and manipulated from there. In XAML, the overridden ToString is displayed like so:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Container.Date.DateString, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
```

Locator is defined in App.xaml:

```
<data:Locator x:Key="Locator" />
```

The Locator class includes:

```
public class Locator
{
    static Locator()
    {
        Container = new GameContainer();
    }

    public static GameContainer Container { get; set; }
}
```

GameContainer includes:

```
public class GameContainer
{
    public GameContainer()
    {
        Date = new Date();
    }

    public Date Date { get; set; }
}
```

I have also tried this with IOC containers with no luck.

When the program is launched, everything behaves properly; a button click increments the date (and calls `RaisePropertyChanged` on `DateString`). However, if I create a new instance of the container or a new instance of `Date`, the UI no longer updates and I can't figure out why. It only seems to happen after user interaction has occurred; I can create a new instance during various stages of the program's initialization without any problems, but once a button click causes a new instance to be created, the string no longer updates.

I have tried everything I can think of and I can't seem to figure out what is causing this to happen. Any help would be appreciated.

Update: Currently my Dependency Property is as follows:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ContainerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Container", typeof(GameContainer), typeof(Locator));

    public static GameContainer Container
    {
        get { return (GameContainer)GetValue(ContainerProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ContainerProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

I'm getting this error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty)'

Comment: `However, if I create a new instance of the container or a new instance of Date, the UI no longer updates and I can't figure out why.`: are you sure you're doing that on the same instance of `Locator` that got bound? I ask because `Locator` isn't a `static` class so you're going to have some synchronization issues there.

Comment: Making `Locator` static makes no difference.

Comment: How are you creating the new instance of the container while the bindings on the UI is still the same? I suspect that your Locator instance is still bound to the UI that's why when you create a new instance it does not update. When do you want the new instance to be created?

Comment: I would like for there to be a Button or MenuItem that overwrites the current `GameContainer` and replaces it with a fresh one and goes through the initialization logic again. At least that's what I've tried to implement.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand very well your question. Have you already tried to update the GameContainer property from your ViewModel, firing the event Click of a button?

Comment: Yes, I have one button that adds a day to `Date`, which works until `GameContainer` is renewed. I have a second button that replaces `GameContainer` with a new instance and runs through the initialization logic again. Once I click the second button, the 'add day' button no longer updates the UI. A breakpoint shows that the date is being incremented, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't have any **property changed notifying mechanism**, this is very important to make the `Binding` work properly. Try implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` or creating the corresponding `DependencyProperty`, I'll introduce to using `DependencyProperty` in this case:

```
public class GameContainer : DependencyObject {
  public GameContainer() {
     Date = new Date();
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty DateProperty = 
       DependencyProperty.Register("Date", typeof(Date), typeof(GameContainer));
  public Date Date {
     get { return (Date) GetValue(DateProperty);}
     set {
        SetValue(DateProperty, value);
     }
  }
}
```

**NOTE**: do the same for the property `Container` in the class `Locator`.

I'm really confused how `Binding` deals with static property. This is all I can think of as a should-try code:

```
public class Locator {       
   static Locator() {
    Container = new GameContainer();
   }
   public static event EventHandler ContainerChanged;
   static GameContainer container;
   public static GameContainer Container {
     get { return container;}
     set {
        if(container != value){
          container = value;
          var handler = ContainerChanged;
          handler(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
     }
   }       
}
```

Comment: I have INPC implemented already; that's how it's working in the first place. I'll try the dependency properties and let you know if that works.

Comment: @JasonD sorry, see update, `GameContainer` should have to inherit from `DependencyObject`.

Comment: @JasonD in the first place, it worked for you because your `Date` was not **actually** changed, just one of its `Data members` changed. BTW, I've experienced the **strange** thing that sometimes `INotifyPropertyChanged` doesn't work but the `DependencyProperty` works OK.

Comment: The problem I'm running into now is that I need for the `GameContainer` object in `Locator` to be static, which is causing trouble.

Comment: I get 2 errors, one on the getter and one on the setter (on the Container property in `Locator`) : `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty)'`

Comment: @JasonD it's so confusing because I can't imagine **how Binding deals with static Property**? Any `Binding` needs **an object** as the `Source`. You're using `Binding` in the wrong way.

Comment: Essentially what I'm trying to accomplish is having one class, `GameContainer` in this case, to act as a central point for data my program uses (and would need to serialize/deserialize). In this case, `GameContainer` will hold an instance of `Date` that can be used elsewhere. I originally was using `Locator` with an IOC container to keep an instance of `GameContainer` and a couple other things globally accessible. I understand that this is probably far from the best way to go about things, but I am far from an experienced programmer and I'm still learning.

Comment: @JasonD please look at the updated code of mine, it's the only solution I can think of (but not sure if it works).

Comment: Unfortunately that gives me a `NullReferenceException` on the Container property. I'll keep digging.

Comment: @JasonD try this link about `static property binding` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588(v=vs.110).aspx#static_properties , I also update the code according to the instruction there, not sure if it works, looks like it supports only since .NET 4.5

Comment: I've been tinkering with this and the event is always null. I'll see what I can find.

Comment: You were absolutely correct from the beginning. I made `Locator` a singleton, added the Dependency Property for `GameContainer` (got rid of `static`), and it works perfectly now. I just wish I had done this 2 hours ago.... Regardless, thank you so much for your help. I certainly appreciate it.

Comment: @JasonD I doubt that you looked at the old code of mine which declared the event `GameContainerChanged` but it should be `ContainerChanged`, also be sure you are using the .NET 4.5 or higher. Some online example shows that it seems to work.